# ¿Guardar datos de 2 SELECT múltiple en la base de datos con PHP y Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Necesito guardar los datos del siguiente formulario:

```html
<form action="registrar.php" method="POST">
  <p><select name="buses" multiple>
    <option selected disabled>Seleccionar buses</option>
    <option value="1">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="2">Wols</option>
    <option value="3">Volvo</option>
    <option value="4">Mitsubishi</option>
    <option value="5">Neptune</option>
  </select></p>
  <p><select name="choferes" multiple>
    <option selected disabled>Seleccionar Choferes</option>
    <option value="72589964">Roberto</option>
    <option value="34558973">Luis</option>
    <option value="01527957">Carlos</option>
    <option value="85585818">Andres</option>
    <option value="45889524">Juan</option>
  </select></p>
  <p><input type="text" name="cliente" placeholder="Ingresa Cliente"></p>
  <p><input type="number" name="monto" placeholder="Ingresa monto"></p>
  <p><button type="submit" action="#" method="POST">Registrar</button></p>
</form>
```

La tabla "servicios" está relacionada con la tabla "movilidades" (id_movilidad) y "choferes" (dni_chofer).

**TABLA SERVICIOS ↓**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Como hago para registrar los select multiple en la tabla y de que manera deberia hacerlo con PHP?**

/*EDITADO:--código php que estoy utilizando**********************************/

```
$sval_1 = $_POST['buses'];
$sval_2 = $_POST['choferes'];
$sval_3 = $_POST['cliente'];
$sval_4 = $_POST['monto'];

$query = "INSERT INTO servicios (cliente,vehiculo,chofer,monto)
VALUES ('$sval_3','$sval_1','$sval_2','$sval_4')";
$result = mysqli_query($conect,$query);
```

**Al momento de presionar el botón Registrar me imprime el error:**
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\sist\registrar.php on line 6

Comment: Puedes revisar la edición del post, acabo de agregarlo, Gracias.

Comment: VALUES ('$sval_3','$sval_1','$sval_2','$sval_4')";

Comment: el $sval_1 y $sval_2 son datos tipo array que se envían por el formulario, pertenecen a los 2 select

Comment: como debería hacerlo?

Comment: Esa es tu pregunta real entonces.. necesitamos uno que sepa bien php ;). Edita la pregunta, acalara todo lo que esta en los comentarios, limpiemos esto y esperemos a alguien que sepa ;)

Comment: Ejecute tal cual y me genero: "INSERT INTO ab_servicios_general (scliente,svehiculo,schofer,smonto) VALUES ('nombre-cliente','1','Roberto','121')" donde se nota que el nombre de las columnas al parecer esta mal, pero no genera el error que comentas, ¿omitiste otra sección ?

Comment: hice una corrección en la pregunta, podéis checarlo porfavor

Answer (score 0):

Buen día, no entiendo muy bien lo que quieres lograr,

Formulario
//se realizó una modificación en el buttom `enviar`

```html
<form action="registrar.php" method="POST">
  <p><select name="buses[]" multiple>
    <option selected disabled>Seleccionar buses</option>
    <option value="1">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="2">Wols</option>
    <option value="3">Volvo</option>
    <option value="4">Mitsubishi</option>
    <option value="5">Neptune</option>
  </select></p>
  <p><select name="choferes[]" multiple>
    <option selected disabled>Seleccionar Choferes</option>
    <option value="72589964">Roberto</option>
    <option value="34558973">Luis</option>
    <option value="01527957">Carlos</option>
    <option value="85585818">Andres</option>
    <option value="45889524">Juan</option>
  </select></p>
  <p><input type="text" name="cliente" placeholder="Ingresa Cliente"></p>
  <p><input type="number" name="monto" placeholder="Ingresa monto"></p>
  <p><button type="submit" value="enviar">Registrar</button></p>
</form>
```

Si solo quieres insertar el `value` de los `select` que enviar en tu formulario por POST

Rescibimos los parametros en tu archivo `registrar.php`

```
 //nos aseguramos de que el usuario presionó enviar
 if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){

  //los serializamos para guardarlo en la BD
  $busesArr = serialize($_POST['buses']);
  $choferesArr = serialize($_POST['choferes']);
  $sval_3 = $_POST['cliente'];
  $sval_4 = $_POST['monto'];

  $query = "INSERT INTO servicios (cliente,vehiculo,chofer,monto)
  VALUES ('".$sval_3."','".$sval_1."','".$sval_2."','".$sval_4."')";

     if(mysqli_query($conect,$query)){
       echo "Datos insertados Correctamente";
           }

 }
```

Nota: A la hora de extraerlo y procesarlo necesitas unserialize()

Saludos

Comment: el codigo que tengo funciona cuando el <select> no es de tipo multiple, el problema llega cuando el select es multiple y doy click en enviar y no almacena nada en la bd y sale error Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\sist\registrar.php on line 6

Comment: listo, revisa la edición.